# Figure insert trouble

Tags: graphics

I want to insert figures (9 row, 2 column size box) in such a way that in left side column, no. of figures should be 9 and it caption start from a, b ,c to i and on the same page in right side column, i can insert 9 figures and their caption should repeat from  a to i. If anybody know the way. Plz help.
I am using this code.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
 \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{5}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{6}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{7}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{8}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{9}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
 \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{5}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{6}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{7}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{8}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{9}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{minipage}
 \caption{Steady base flow, $Re=100,\; Ar=1.0$}
 \label{Fig:Steady_flow_Re100}
 \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

If you want to add captions for each figures,  use the similar way of captioning. It will work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE (minimal working example of code that you've got so far) or at least a graphical representation of what you want.

Comment: `\begin{figure*}\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth} ... 9 figures in \subfloat or in \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}...\end{subfigure} ... \caption{...}\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth} ... 9 figures  ... \caption{...}\end{minipage}\end{figure*}` ?For more specific solution (in form of answer) you need to show us what you try so far in form of small, complete document with `\documentclass{...}` on beginning and `\end{document}` on the end.

Comment: It's working. Exactly the way i wanted to. Many thanks to you.

Comment: @DeepakKumar, anyway, you should provide MWE, as you was asked twice. With it I/we can formulate (convert my comment to) an answer for you. Otherwise your question will be closed as "off-topic".

Comment: Sorry ! I didn't get you. What should i provide? I mean my code is too long to post here. I tried but it shows too long words. anyway i have posted what i tried. But your code works for me. thanks

Comment: \begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
   \begin{subfigure}[h!]{1\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{W/W_1}
   \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
   \caption{ \;$Re=100, Ar=0.01$}
   \label{fig:Ng1} 
\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}[h!]{1\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{W/W_75}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
   
\end{subfigure} \end{figure}

Comment: @DeepakKumar, not in comment! Please edit your question and add there what propose *TeXnician* and me in our comment. Let me repeat: MWE (Minimal Working Example) is small, complete document, which we can copy and as it is compile in our computers to see your problem. This document we can then more easy improve on the way that it will solve your problem. This solution can be value information to other users of TeX.SE, if they will experience the similar problem.

Comment: @DeepakKumar, also make sure that your minimal working example (MWE) is complete. In other words, that it begins with `\documentclass[...]` and ends with `\end{document}`. Anyone here should be able to just copy and paste your code to test it and then help you. As Zarko mentioned, edit your original post and add your code there.

Comment: I am sorry. I was little late. I was stuck with my work. anyway I have updated my question.  This website is very helpful.  I am  a new user so don't know much but it helps me a lot while writing my report.

Comment: @DeepakKumar full minimal example please, there is no preamble here and no document class. BTW: you problably do not want to use `\textwidth` as the `width` arg here, rather `\linewidth` as that adapts to the minipages, `\textwidth` does not.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand, this is what you're after. Some things to note:

- Each image is followed by a `\caption{}`, which is what generates the number.
- Here I used the `demo` option for the `graphicx` package, but you must remove that in your code. It replaces images with black rectangles.
- I also set the `height` for image explicitly, but you probably don't want to do that in your document, so remove `height=1cm` from all the `\includegraphics`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove demo in your document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{1} %remove height=1cm in your document
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{2}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{3}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{4}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{5}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{6}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{7}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{8}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{9}
 \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Steady base flow, $Re=100,\; Ar=1.0$}
\label{Fig:Steady_flow_Re100}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{1} %remove height=1cm in your document
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{2}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{3}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{4}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{5}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{6}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{7}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{8}
 \caption{}

 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{9}
 \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Something else}
\label{Fig:something}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```